# Please explain TSQL code:

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can someone help explain the following code:

```
convert(datetime, substring(column, 0, 23))
```

What is going on here? Is the code converting a datetime field and returning it? If so then what format should it return.

Comment: It's converting a string to a datetime.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)  The string itself comes from a substring of a column's value.

Comment: Please post a couple of `column` values from the table. Seems like an attempt to strip the timezone info.

Comment: Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Why don't you read the part of the manual that documents what `convert()` is doing?

Comment: I did - convert() is easy enough to understand, the problem I have is with what convert() is doing to the substring...

Answer (score 1):

The word `CONVERT` means "change something into a different form" (see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/convert). The `CONVERT` function changes whatever it's given in the second parameter to the type given in the first (if possible).

`SubString` retrieves the portion of the string between a starting and ending index (in this case, positions `0` and `23`).

So the statement retrieves the portion of the column using SubString() from the indexes given and converts that character string value to `DATETIME`.

Comment: Thanks Ken - I am starting to get a good understanding on this now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is  converting the first 23 characters that could be found on the column specified on the substring method to a value that will have a datetime as it's type.

Answer (score 0):

Give the answer (check) to Allan as he was first
But this will help you understand

```
select convert(datetime, substring(column, 0, 23)), 
                         substring(column, 0, 23) , 
                                   column 
from ...
```